# Sharing link on WhatsApp from Android App using Intel xdk

Tags: android, intel, intel-xdk

Hi i am trying to build a small app using intel xdk .The app main concept is to share text to whatsapp using the android app.

```
<body><a href="whatsapp://send?text=<<HERE GOES THE URL ENCODED TEXT YOU WANT TO SHARE>>” data-action=”share/whatsapp/share”>Share via Whatsapp</a></body>
```

it works in intel App preview but when i build the apk it does nothing
Plz try to slove this.

Comment: App Preview is currently build with Cordova CLI 3.5, there are some issues with some devices and CLI 4.1.2 that might be related to your problem -- I'm not sure -- but you can test that theory by setting the CLI to 3.5 in your build settings and see if this works in a built app. Also, be sure to set the Domain Whitelist to *

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if you are declaring share permissions in yoi Android Manifest file (or the Android section of your intel xdk config file).